# Laravel ajax respond appending to body but not to #results

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem with outputting results from search in a div with id 'results' if I append the results to body they show up but when I change it to #results it's never appearing.

Search box is in navigation in master.blade.php and every other page includes it.

master.blade.php

```
 <form id="search_form" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value);" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <div id="result">
            <table style="width:100%">
    @if (isset($results) && count($results) > 0)
    @foreach( $results as $business )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $business->logo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $business->name}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
</table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function search($search_value) {
    $search_text = $search_value;
    if ($search_text==NULL) {
        $data= Business::all();
    } else {
        $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
    }
    //$data = $data->toArray();
    return view('master')->with('results',$data);
    }
```

Ajax:

```
function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/searching/' + search_value,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').append(data);
        },
        error: function(data) { 
            $('body').html(data); 
        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }       
    });
}
```

Route::

```
Route::post('/searching/{search}', 'SearchController@search');
```

If I actually look into ajax response, result is there:

```
<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>dasd</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But it never appears on the page! It does if the append is changed to body.

//edit

I have a loading gif which worked fine but now it never dissapears and each time it executed ajax, it doesn't want to dissapear too:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { Pace.restart(); });
$(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('.se-pre-con').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(".container").css({ opacity: 1.0 });
            });
        }); // set the time here
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".messages").fadeOut(5000);
});
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".messages").fadeOut(5000);
});
});
```

css:

```
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #6d6968;
    background: url(../images/default.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

Comment: Rename id <div id="result"> to <div id="show_search_result"> 
and also in  ajax  
success: function(data) {
            $('#results').append(data); -> replace with $('#show_search_result').append(data);
        },

Comment: why did that work? why wouldn't results work

Comment: I think you are getting this issue because of "result" id use more then one time in same page. Check it first.

Comment: yeah that's true actually, see my edit please

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, data) {
            $('.se-pre-con').show();
    },
    complete: function ()
    {
        $('.se-pre-con').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: but the gif doesn't disappear even when I don't execute ajax, i.e. refresh the page, while before it did

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.